# How to pull each image src tag froma string and replace entire img tag

Tags: php, regex

I would like to be able to read each image's src attribute from a string and if it matches replace the entire img tag with a different format. My current regular expression is not working. It replaces the beginning of the img tag but leaves all the other attributes inside like style, rel, title, ect. Here is an example of my logic:

```
$message = 'I AM SENDING YOU AND IMAGE <image src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/bessie-colemans-125th-birthday-5751652702224384-scta.png" rel="test image" style="display: block;" /> SEE THE IMAGE?';

function replacelinks($message) {
    $ret = preg_replace_callback('/(<img\s+src=["\'])([^"\']+)(["\']\s+[^>]+>)/', function ($m) { $url = parse_url($m[1]); if ($url['path'].$url['query'] == "/logos/doodles/2017/bessie-colemans-125th-birthday-5751652702224384-scta.png") { return '{IMG::'.$url['path'].$url['query'].'}'; } }, $message);
return $ret;
}

echo replacelinks($message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the regex from:

```
/(<img\s+src=["\'])([^"\']+)(["\']\s+[^>]+>)/
```

to this:

```
~<img[^>]*?src="(.*?(\w+))".*?>~
```

It works!